# Reset password link not working in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

In my laravel project i used `php artisan make:auth` command. If i click forgot password and give my email there are no link in my mail account. 
Here my `.env` file i changed

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=cloudclassroombd@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=681757612
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

And in mail.php i changed

```
'from' => ['address' => 'cloudclassroombd@gmail.com', 'name' => 'cloudclassroombd'],
```

And in my gmail account which mail sent the link that mail i on Allow less secure apps: On.

Now where is the problem still now here?